# Having trouble pulling X-Mailer header flags from an email even though request extra header is set

Tags: ios, imap, mailcore2

I'm at my wits end trying to pull the "X-Mailer" header from an email. All other seems to work fine. Any ideas on how to debug / what I might possibly be doing wrong?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
message.header.allExtraHeadersNames; => ()
message.header.userAgent; => "(null)"
[message.header extraHeaderValueForName:@"X-Mailer"] => "(null)
```

I'm requesting these headers:

```
return (MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind)
(MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindStructure |
     MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindInternalDate | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaderSubject |
     MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindGmailThreadID | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFullHeaders |
     MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindGmailLabels | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindExtraHeaders |
     MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags);
```

I can validate that the correct RequestKindHeaders is being sent as I am able to pull the correct GmailThreadID:

```
message.gmailThreadID; => 1504802571269374502
```

And the email header as per Gmail's "original message".

```
Delivered-To: vu0tran@xxxxx.com
Received: by 10.70.126.36 with SMTP id mv4csp3102740pdb;
        Tue, 23 Jun 2015 14:25:31 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.13.219.13 with SMTP id d13mr6638173ywe.22.1435094730675;
        Tue, 23 Jun 2015 14:25:30 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bounce-mc.us6_12976611.827941-vu0tran=gmail.com@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net>
Received: from mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net (mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net. [205.201.134.84])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id e184si9259660ywa.76.2015.06.23.14.25.29
        for <vu0tran@gmail.com>;
        Tue, 23 Jun 2015 14:25:29 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounce-mc.us6_12976611.827941-vu0tran=gmail.com@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net designates 205.201.134.84 as permitted sender) client-ip=205.201.134.84;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce-mc.us6_12976611.827941-vu0tran=gmail.com@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net designates 205.201.134.84 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bounce-mc.us6_12976611.827941-vu0tran=gmail.com@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=k1; d=mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net;
 h=From:Reply-To:To:Date:Message-ID:List-ID:List-Unsubscribe:Sender:Subject:Content-Type; i=vu=XXXXXXXX.com@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net;
 bh=rAP8hOadQtBeDm6jm9/SrnV0Y/o=;
 b=pp/7bQcQFZXsajvEDHf+faCrkOg95UyrcpZ1NUVzt3O5dxSWmjhefcytwvQiVbcw8FIyyekpZMke
   ezAjhCRqZKyM0xafVQGtqVX2jKmDsgyA5r0cV2FBa8ObFX+mMjHRDYVzXrW+QfKlrc9buaNZwv9Q
   VZVWotIxzZKHn9Qu8gE=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=k1; d=gmail.mcsv.net;
 h=From:Reply-To:To:Date:Message-ID:X-Feedback-ID:List-ID:List-Unsubscribe:Sender:Subject:Content-Type;
 bh=rAP8hOadQtBeDm6jm9/SrnV0Y/o=;
 b=l5yRKHMnZEW1slk+VOypUZ3r/24fJjff022IE2p9fiOUDBIx+UiHYdWyMdt6jhH85UDDOEHstnDe
   OYBJfj80RXqduVRvnaSRDRtZV1W3PCZFLfoLcAS72V0cCHaRZBBojIwlOJFcmXKdBM2TxC5D8yOq
   7t4fUwaXmIsLYl6eovg=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=k1; d=mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net;
 b=nLYfHDRQzNRmbnWc8tnSDAZtiWu4E+aGOZBFBUVz44vR+I47xEpuY4ac0KFL+Uc01K66tVX+kj+9
   EbocAToElbAndJ6WD6YYnkgBdKz03OaANjesAvwIPe1jH/+Zqfw3eQUHGGTJuYKsPD6a4f+sldll
   YNnpCr6MUwStCDm6obU=;
Received: from (127.0.0.1) by mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net id hh77ci1mqrog for <vu0tran@gmail.com>; Tue, 23 Jun 2015 21:25:29 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-mc.us6_12976611.827941-vu0tran=gmail.com@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net>)
From: =?utf-8?Q?XXXXXXX?= <vu@XXXXXX.com>
Reply-To:  <us6-40dbc13c7a-bf64292c7d@inbound.mailchimp.com>
To: =?utf-8?Q?=3C=3C=20Test=20First=20Name=20=3E=3E?= <vu0tran@gmail.com>
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 21:25:29 +0000
Message-ID: <afe03fcb279af0d81939903e7.20150623212521@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net>
X-Mailer: MailChimp Mailer - **CID31045d1dc9**
X-Campaign: mailchimpafe03fcb279af0d81939903e7.31045d1dc9
X-campaignid: mailchimpafe03fcb279af0d81939903e7.31045d1dc9
X-Report-Abuse: Please report abuse for this campaign here: http://www.mailchimp.com/abuse/abuse.phtml?u=afe03fcb279af0d81939903e7&id=31045d1dc9&e=
X-MC-User: afe03fcb279af0d81939903e7
X-Feedback-ID: 12976611:12976611.827941:us6:mc
List-ID: afe03fcb279af0d81939903e7mc list <afe03fcb279af0d81939903e7.121893.list-id.mcsv.net>
X-Accounttype: ff
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe-afe03fcb279af0d81939903e7-31045d1dc9-@mailin1.us2.mcsv.net?subject=unsubscribe>, <http://vutran.us6.list-manage.com/unsubscribe?u=afe03fcb279af0d81939903e7&id=fe48c8ecec&e=&c=31045d1dc9>
Sender: "XXXXXX" <vu=XXXXXX.com@mail84.atl31.mcdlv.net>
x-istest: yes
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=5BTest=5D=20Introducing=20email=20filtering?=
x-mcda: TRUE
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
```

Comment: The header appears to be here: "X-Mailer: MailChimp Mailer - **CID31045d1dc9**"

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Correct. This is the header I EXPECT to be able to pull. It is copied and pasted from Gmail. However, I cannot seem to access it via Mailcore2. Any ideas?

Comment: MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation * op = ... ; op.extraHeaders = @[@"X-Mailer"]; [op start];